# Working example for Leaflet Geosearch in react

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

Excuse my ignorance, but being new to react and JS, I am getting ***irate*** trying to follow the docs for https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch/ &

https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch

I have the following react leaflet component working just fine:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer} from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.css';
import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

const AutoCompleteAddress = () => {

    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

    const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
        provider: provider,
    });



    return (
        <>
            <h1>map</h1>

            <MapContainer center={[0, 0]} zoom={2} style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }}>
                <TileLayer
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                />
            </MapContainer>
        </>
    );
};

export default AutoCompleteAddress;
```

Anytime I try to move this code further looking at any of the various examples in the docs I get errors, referencing the libraries. I just want to use GeoSearchControl as here:

```
autoComplete: true, // optional: true|false  - default true

autoCompleteDelay: 250, // optional: number      - default 250
```

so that I dont have to build my own dropdown using the results object

```
provider.search({ query: input.value });
```

any assistance here would be appreciated!

Further, how to use GeoSearchControl without leaflet?